# Can I choose who to induct at Sky Haven temple while using Amazing Follower Tweaks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing Skyrim VR with the [Amazing Follower Tweaks mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/6656). I would like to induct a couple of my followers into the temple, but I want to pick out who they are.

The problem I have is, AFT lets me have multiple followers. But the dialogue option for Blades initiation with Delphine assumes I only have one follower. When I select this option, only one of my current followers is inducted, so AFT and/or Skyrim are picking one of my followers somehow. Is there some way I can influence this decision, or is the follower always picked effectively at random?

Comment: AFT only manages your followers IMO. Initiation into the Blades is done by talking to Delphine.

Comment: @LoreFriendly I edited my question in response to your comment. Does the problem I'm having make more sense now?

Comment: I do not have a way to play test it, and I use NFF so YMMV. NFF has a slot called a "game slot" and you have to manually move a follower from say Slot 1 to game slot for the blades initiation to work. This is the vanilla follower slot and the only way for the game to recognize that you have a follower.

Comment: AFT does things differently. You could try this. I have a bound key for "Wait All". I usually do a Wait All, then ask the one follower to follow and do the dialogue for initiation. But again no way for me to test it right now.